# I am not able to get data from newly added row during submit

Tags: angular

I have an array with below formGroup.

```
return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      address: new FormGroup({
        value: new FormControl(null),
        currency: new FormControl(currency),
        state: new FormControl(null),
      }),
   })
```

I add a new row from my function to my existing formGroup.

Here is how I have added a new row:

```
  addNewRow() {
    const newItem = this.newFormGroup('EUR');
    this.rowdata.insert(0, newItem);
  }

  get rowData(): FormArray {
    return this.formDisplay.get('order') as FormArray;
  }
```

on my submit function, I am trying to get data which added. I am able to get all data besides address. How can I get its data in submit function?